# Listing user ids from all guilds (discord.js)

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm aware that some of the elements in this code has probably been deprecated. However, I found this code and I have altered it to some extent but I am receiving a error. I'm looking to fetch user ids in **all** guilds, I understand that you can get ratelimited by the amount of users in all guilds.

> TypeError: client.guilds.forEach is not a function

```js
// guild member ids
client.on('message', message => {
    if (message.content === '$listmids') {
        if (message.author.id !== "651167823749578798") return;
        client.guilds.forEach(member => {
            console.log(`${member.id}`)

            var idserver = (`${member.id}`) // id each guild
            var memserver = client.guilds.get(idserver); // check guild with id

            memserver.members.forEach(member => {
                console.log(member.user.id); // console.log see id user in that guild
            }); // get userid all guild
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: You are getting that error because you are using outdated code. To use `forEach` you need to use the `cache` property: `client.guilds.cache.forEach({})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to fetch the users, they are already cached. You can't use [`GuildManager.fetch()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v12/class/GuildManager?scrollTo=fetch) nor [`UserManager.fetch()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v12/class/UserManager?scrollTo=fetch) to fetch all the users or guilds, since it has an id ([Twitter Snowflake](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v12/typedef/Snowflake)) as a **required** parameter (referring to @MrMythical's answer).

When a discord bot is started an event `GUILD_CREATE` is emitted on the websocket for each guild. The client uses this to cache all the `.guilds` and `.users`, etc.

So you can simply use:

```js
// An array of user ids
const users = client.users.cache.map(u => u.id);
```

To implement this in a command:

```js
client.on("message", (message) => {

    if (message.author.id == client.user.id) return;

    if (message.content == "$listmids") {
        const users = client.users.cache.map(u => u.id);
        console.log(`Listing user ids from all guilds:`);
        console.log(users);
    }

});
```

[image]

You can also use the websocket event `GUILD_CREATE` to log all user ids to console on bot's startup:

```js
client.ws.on("GUILD_CREATE", (data) => {
    console.log(`Listing user ids from a guild '${data.name}'`);
    console.log(data.members.map(m => m.user.id));
});
```

[image]

---

As for compatibility with discord.js `13.x.x`, it is fully compatible, but you need `GUILDS` intent to receive `GUILD_CREATE` on the websocket. And `GUILD_PRESENCES` intent to include the users in the guild data.

Also `GUILD_MESSAGES` for the command to work. And listen (`client.on(...)`) for `messageCreate` instead of `message`, it is deprecated.

```js
const client = new Discord.Client({ intents: ["GUILDS", "GUILD_MESSAGES", "GUILD_PRESENCES"] });
```

<sup>Using discord.js `^12.5.3`.</sup>

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you won’t get ratelimited for doing things that are only on your side. Secondly, how you do this is by fetching `client.users`.

```js
//async function
const users = await client.users.fetch()
//users is a Collection of user objects. You can map by user id
const userIds = users.map(u => u.id)
//userIds is an Array of user Ids
```

Comment: `.map()` returns an array, not a `Collection`, so `userIds` will be an array of user IDs.

Comment: The reason I mentioned "ratelimited" is because in the future I plan to invoke a command instead.